# How to switch syntax on and off in vim with one key

Tags: vim

How can i switch syntax highlighting on and off in vim with **one key** ( for instance `<F5>`) in command mode and/or in insert mode at any time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `help g:syntax_on`:

> You can toggle the syntax on/off with this command:

```
   :if exists("g:syntax_on") | syntax off | else | syntax enable | endif
```

> To put this into a mapping, you can use:

```
   :map <F7> :if exists("g:syntax_on") <Bar>              
        \   syntax off <Bar>                             
        \ else <Bar>                                     
        \   syntax enable <Bar>                                  
        \ endif <CR>
```

> [using the <> notation, type this literally]

To get it in insert mode, the simplest way, I think, is to do

```
imap <F7> <C-o>F7
```

In my .vimrc i have the same, but with `nnoremap` and `<silent>`:

```
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>ts
             \ : if exists("syntax_on") <BAR>
             \    syntax off <BAR>
             \ else <BAR>  
             \    syntax enable <BAR>
             \ endif<CR>
```